# What is the best way to change an API

Tags: c, refactoring

Im currently changing a set of kernel APIs that are used in about 40 different files. How do I go about refactoring them? Is it a good practice to have the old API call the new one thus eliminating my going through every file and making changes? By doing this I'm essentially saying that all old code using this API is fine but newer code should not(Although there would be no way of enforcing this via code). #baddesign

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a good practice(as you have rightly mentioned) to gradually "retire" an existing API in favor of a new one; in the meantime continuing to provide the older API for backward compatibility.

Currently you need to mark the function(s) part of the existing older API as **deprecated**. This can be done by specifying the ["**deprecated**" compiler function-attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) during the function definition as follows.

```
int old_fn () __attribute__ ((deprecated (<optional-msg>)));
```

Now during compilation, a warning is generated if any part of the code attempts to call the deprecated function. The warning contains the **file** and **line** from where the deprecated function is being called. Also if the optional ***msg*** parameter is specified, it will be logged to the screen along-with the warning.

To guide the developers using your framework towards the new API, you can add additional info to the ***msg*** string. For example, the name of the new function that is recommended henceforth in lieu of the deprecated function.

Comment: You need double parentheses, I believe.  The GCC 4.8.1 manual illustrates: `int old_fn () __attribute__ ((deprecated));` and also describes `deprecated` and `deprecated (msg)`.

Comment: Updated answer with the double parentheses as described in the gcc manual.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!